# How to redirect requests to subdirectory url to root in Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, https, apache2, vhosts

I have Apache httpd server running in my Linux box with SSL enabled using LetsEncrypt. The root directory of html files is `/var/www/html`. Let me show the structure of `/var/www/html` below;

```
 -html
  |_ index.php
  |_ file1.php
  |_ dir1
  |  |_ index.php
  |_ dir2
     |_ index.php
```

I am able to access the website using `https://example.com` url. What I am trying to achieve is if the user try to access `https://example.com/dir3` (which is not present), the `index.php` file of root directory should be delivered. Or, if the user try to access `https://example.com/dir3/file1.php` , the file `file1.php` of root should be delivered.

I tried editing virtual host in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf` but is showing file not found. Let me describe `vhost-le-ssl.conf` below;

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com

  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ServerAdmin info@example.com

  Alias /dir3 "/var/www/html"

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule dir3/* /var/www/html [R=301]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `dir3` a  definitively known dir name or shall it represent *"any, but not dir1 or dir2"*?

Comment: hi @dodrg dir3 url pattern is constant and I am not looking for solution "any, but not dir1 or dir2"

Answer (score 0):

As `dir3`, the "unwanted" directory, is known, there are two obvious possibilities.

#### 1. SymLink the folder.

To create the symlink

```bash
ln -s '.' '/var/www/html/dir3'
```

will make the folder existent, but shows to the content of `/`.
This has some implications:

- Recursion: As `dir3` will become in itself visible again and enabling  URLs like `http://example.com/dir3/dir3/dir3/dir3/index.html`. Thats rarely desirable.
- Dependencies: If `/index.html` contains references that rely on its original position, these might fail, depending on the details.

#### 2. ReWrite Rules

The other possibility is to use rewrite rules.

File:  `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^(/dir3)(/.*)"
RewriteRule ".*" "%2" [R=301,NC,L]
```

`R=301` tells to signal a permanent redirect:

- The rewritten location will become visible in the address bar
- Search engines will learn the new address as the successor of the old one (keeps SEO up)
  This is usefull when migrating from an old structure to a new one.

###### Alternative:

If you prefer to **hide the redirection** from the visitor and the search engines, just omit the `R=301,`:

File:  `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^(/dir3)(/.*)"
RewriteRule ".*" "%2" [NC,L]
```

###### When server conf is prefered:

If you have the possibility to edit the conf-files of your Apache and prefer to disable the use of `.htaccess`-files, you can configure your rules there by defining the folder they should apply to:

File: `httpd.conf`  or `yourVirtualHost.conf`

```xml
<Directory /var/www/html>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^(/dir3)(/.*)"
    RewriteRule ".*" "%2" [R=301,NC,L]
</Directory>
```